# Fetching data from QueryDatabaseTable in NiFi

Tags: mysql, apache, apache-nifi

I have a Database in MySQL that has almost 2 million row count and 30 columns. My flow is QueryDatabaseTable -> convertrecord -> PutElasticSearchHttpRecord. My QueryDatabaseTable has following configs (please see the screenshots):

[image]

[image]

My Jjava.args values are as follows: **(Although I updated the values of following two as 8 GB, still I am getting java heap space error**)

**java.arg.2=-Xms512m
java.arg.3=-Xmx512m**

I am applying **select * from Tablename** (will result in 749,748 rows across 9 columns) but getting "Java heap space Error". Is it because i am trying to call 749,748 rows across 9 columns?

What will be the best way to call such huge dataset from MySQL using NiFi QueryDatabaseTable processor. Any help is much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, after updating jvm heap space to `8GB` did you restarted the `NiFi`?, after restart then only nifi will run with `8GB JVM memory`.

Comment: @Shu yes Thank you! I didnt stop and restarted the NiFi. Now it is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in above comments.

`NiFi default JVM` configs are **`java.arg.2=-Xms512m java.arg.3=-Xmx512m`** and this is root cause for the ***outofmemory*** issue.

To resolve this issue `increase` the the heap space in **`$NIFI_HOME/conf/bootstrap.conf`** file

As per your requirement change the configs as shown below i have increased the heap space to `8GB`

```
# JVM memory settings
java.arg.2=-Xms8912m
java.arg.3=-Xmx8912m
```

And to get these configs take into effect in your NiFi instance, **`RESTART`** the whole NiFi instance, Then only the NiFi instance will run with the `configured heap space`.

For more details regards to JVM outofmemory issues refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/85234/how-to-address-jvm-outofmemory-errors-in-nifi.html) link.